# Why do programatically created Excel charts look like they are 10 years old?

Tags: excel, charts, labview

I am trying to programatically generate Excel 2010 charts (specifically scatter plots) in LabVIEW using the Excel Insert Graph.vi. When I open Excel and select data and create the chart it looks nice and new and easily configurable. When I use the VI to do it, it looks old and ugly and clicking on it to get options takes away my ribbon and appears to transport me back to 2003-land. I'm assuming this works the same way in VB/C# Excel graphing but I haven't tested it. Does anyone know why I can't access the newer charts when graphing through my program? I am using xlxyScatter as the chart type.

Comment: Weird. After more experimentation it appears that only Excel Insert Graph.vi which is part of the Report Generation Toolkit pulls this old version of graphs. If I use the SAME ENUM on the Excel ActiveX commands it will give me the newer version of the chart.

Comment: You can look in the Report Generation Toolkit to see what template or Excel functions it calls. I don't have the toolkit (or MS Office) installed.

Comment: Interesting...I can get into those VIs. I had just assumed they were password protected like most of the NI stuff. Thanks!

Comment: If NI has locked code with a password, there are normally some rationale:
*The code (if altered) can do harm
*The code is very obscure
*The code is badly written
For the Report Generation, the last might be valid. However it is written so bad, that it's better to open the code to the end user so they can fix it.

Comment: You can write a VB script (inside your excel file) to plot the data and call that script withing labview. In this way, your charts will be modern.